# gulp, browserSync not always reloading

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am using gulp with browserSync watching for file changes. It works fine just oftentimes the browser stalls after a automatic reload with the console message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

All I need to do is <kbd>F5</kbd>, but it's annoying. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm dealing with this same issue...